# How to remove Windows 7 partition and install Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a dual-boot with Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 20.04. I'd like to upgrade Windows by removing W7 first and then install W10 from scratch.
Here is my disk lay-out:
[image: gparted disk lay-out]

- sda1: boot partition Windows
- sda2: Windows 7 installation
- (sda3: extended partition)
- sda5: /root partition of ubuntu
- sda6: swap partition
- sda7: /home partition

I assume I have to do following steps:

1. Remove partition sda1 & sda2
2. Install Windows 10 on the unallocated space
3. Repair grub using [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) or using a [live-cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal)

ps 1: I've created a backup of my whole drive using clonezilla in case of.. 
ps 2: Both os are installed in bios mode hence no no efi partition

Should this give the desired result of having a dualboot with W10 alongside Ubuntu?
Do I overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed the above steps and all went well.

I summarize and mark this as the answer:

1. Remove the boot partition of Windows (sda1) + Windows partition (sda2) (Ubuntu is still bootable)
2. Install Windows on the unallocated space[image: Windows installation choose partition]
3. Windows will reboot after installation. From then on only Windows is bootable.
4. Reboot from the [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) and choose `Recommended Repair`. This will take some minutes. Review the log - normally it should have found Ubuntu & Windows OS partitions.
5. Reboot again and now you should be presented with GRUB menu on boot

This process is really straightforward. Just pay attention to which partition(s) are assigned to Windows and always make a backup before you perform these steps (!).